# rich:editor button component repeating in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, richfaces, text-editor

I am a front-end web developer currently working on a project that is using RichFaces. One of the components being used is a text-editor as shown in the code block below:

```html
<rich:editor viewMode="html" styleClass="text-editor-basic" value="#{advAdditionalPagesBean.cssHTMLCode}" id="cssHTMLCodeEditor" theme="advanced">
    <f:param name="theme_advanced_buttons1"
         value="bold,italic,underline,cut,copy,paste,pasteword,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink" />
    <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_location" value="top" />
    <f:param name="theme_advanced_toolbar_align" value="left" />
</rich:editor>
```

The issue I am having is with IE8. For some reason the forecolor and backcolor components are repeating vertically, which does not happen with IE7, Firefox, or Chrome. See screenshot below:

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I have no idea what HTML/JS that thing generates and what attributes it accepts, but I find those `,|,` suspicious. Shouldn't those be just `|`? I also think that the issue is more related to the generated JS code rather than the generated CSS code.

Comment: @BalusC Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with the syntax that is required for the components. The <rich:editor> tags were completed by the devs working on the backend. I did try all kinds of variations with the `,|,` but without both `,` the forecolor and backcolor components do not render.

Comment: @BalusC As to what HTML/JS that is generated, it is pretty complex. Basically it creates a <div> container with more divs and spans and a table. The table gets even more complex with divs inside of table cells and more tables...on and on it goes. It is very messy, lol. As to the JS, I am uncertain.

Comment: If the issue does lay within the generated JS code, I would think others would see the same issue when using the richfaces editor. Plus, since the JS is generated when the element is rendered in the browser, it would stand to reason that it is more of a CSS problem, that some particular CSS property Faces generates is not working with IE8 and causing the issue...maybe. Thoughts?